# Query to select data between two times?

Tags: sql, ms-access, between

I'm working with Microsoft Access and SQL

I'm trying to select records from table between two times: 6:00:00PM and 11:59:00PM.

Right now I have

```
SELECT RESERVATION.Reservation_ID, SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_Time 
FROM RESERVATION 
INNER JOIN SEAT_RESERVED ON RESERVATION.Reservation_ID = SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_ID 
WHERE timestamps SEAT_RESERVED.RESERVATION_TIME between ('6:00:00PM' and '11:59:00PM');
```

But this isn't working and the error says it's missing an operator. Please help

Comment: Please explain your `WHERE` clause.  What is `timestamps`?

Comment: The error is in your WHERE clause.  Timestamps SEAT_RESERVED ... etc. doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two tables and only 2 different columns. It would be a better practice to put it all in one table. However, if you do want to keep your tables, this is what your schema should look like

Make sure your reservation time is of type `datetime`, `time`, or `timestamps`. In your case, it looks like you are using the timestamps selector.

```
CREATE TABLE reservation(
  reservation_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  reservation_name VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE seat_reserved(
  reservation_id INT,
  reservation_time TIMESTAMP
);
```

Make sure, you're inserting the correct data into your tables.

```
INSERT INTO reservation(reservation_name)
VALUES("George"), ("Roger"), ("John"), ("Lucas");

INSERT INTO seat_reserved(reservation_id, reservation_time)
VALUES(1, "2016-03-08 17:00:00"), 
      (2, "2016-03-08 18:00:00"), 
      (3, "2016-03-08 19:30:00"), 
      (4, "2016-03-08 12:00:00");
```

Pay attention to the values we're inserting into the `reservation_time` column.

The `timestamps` data type returns a date and a time in 24 hour format.

To select the time portion of a timestamps data-type, you can use the `TIME` function.

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/time.php

```
SELECT RESERVATION.Reservation_ID, SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_Time 
FROM RSERVATION
INNER JOIN SEAT_RESERVED ON RESERVATION.Reservation_ID = SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_ID 
WHERE TimeValue(SEAT_RESERVED.RESERVATION_TIME) BETWEEN #18:00:00# AND #23:59:00#
```

I also removed the `timestamps` part in the WHERE clause because that's incorrect syntax.

I created a fiddle for you to play around with

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83bcf5/6/0

Comment: Thank you it worked but how do I specify AM or PM? I put WHERE HOUR(SEAT_RESERVED.RESERVATION_TIME) BETWEEN '6:00:00pm' AND '11:00:00pm' and it shows everything from 12PM to 1159 PM

Comment: `HOUR(SEAT_RESERVED.RESERVATION_TIME) BETWEEN 18 AND 23`

Comment: Happy to help. If you found it interesting, don't forget to mark it as the answer

Comment: but using the hour function wont allow you to query for specific minutes and seconds right ?

Comment: Good catch, I fixed that with the `TIME` function

Comment: This question was initially tagged `mysql` so I answered for that database. But can anyone confirm that this works with `msaccess`. I don't have that database, and `sqlfiddle` doesn't have it as an option.

Comment: On the page you linked: *"There are no parameters or arguments for the Time function."*

Comment: For Access SQL, this should work: `TimeValue(SEAT_RESERVED.RESERVATION_TIME) BETWEEN #18:00:00# AND #23:59:00#`  So should `HOUR(SEAT_RESERVED.RESERVATION_TIME) BETWEEN 18 AND 23` for what Hailey wanted.

Comment: Yeah HansUp is correct and it is also shown in the answer I posted below : )

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT RESERVATION.Reservation_ID, SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_Time 
FROM RESERVATION 
INNER JOIN SEAT_RESERVED ON RESERVATION.Reservation_ID = SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_ID 
WHERE  TimeValue(SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_Time)  >= TimeValue ('6:00:00PM') 
AND TimeValue(SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_Time)  <= TimeValue ('11:59:00PM');
```

or

```
SELECT RESERVATION.Reservation_ID, SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_Time 
FROM RESERVATION 
INNER JOIN SEAT_RESERVED ON RESERVATION.Reservation_ID = SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_ID 
WHERE  TimeValue(SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_Time)  BETWEEN  TimeValue ('6:00:00PM') 
AND TimeValue ('11:59:00PM');
```

Both these queries return what you need. The problem is that you need the where clause to have the SEAT_RESERVED.Reservation_Time not timestamps. Another thing to point out is to convert the values specified in the query into a time value. Using the TimeValue function will allow you to convert a specific text into a timevalue allowing you to query between specific times including minutes and seconds.

Hope you find this helpful.